# does hp deskjet ink advantage 1515 all in one scanner works with ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, printing

I started using ubuntu 12.04 about a week ago.
I can use the print function but I just cant use the scan.
Every time I use simple scan or xsane it displays that it cant find any devices.
any and all helps will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to review HPLIP support.

http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/downloads.html

http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/deskjet_aio/deskjet_1510_series.html